# How can I make a List containing Stats that has Values?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can I make an Array containing `stats` that has values to them like shown below?

I know this specific code does not work, but is there any way to do something like it?

```
string[] stats = new string[] 
{ 
    Money = 100,
    income = 5,
};
```

And if I would like to see all `stats` in a list:

```
foreach (string var in stats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(var.ToString());
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Money = 100
>
> Income = 5

And so on...

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a class called `stats` and override the `ToString` method like this:

```
public class Stats
{
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public int Income { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Money + " " + Income;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
List<Stats> stats = new List<Stats>
{
     new Stats
     {
         Money = 100,
         Income = 5
     },
     new Stats
     {
         Money = 200,
         Income = 10
     }
};

foreach (var item in stats)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

    //Or like this:
     Console.WriteLine("Money = {0} , Income = {1}", item.Money , item.Income);

    //Or with c#6 Interpolated Strings
     Console.WriteLine($"Money = {item.Money}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Income = {item.Income}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
   Dictionary<string,int> Values = new Dictionary<string,int>();
   Values.Add("Money",100);
   Values.Add("Income",5);
```

where key would be(string) money,income etc and value 100, 5(value) etc

Comment: This one I have tried actually. However when I try to temper with the Money I get an error saying that the key already exists.

Comment: In dictionary you can add only unique keys.If you want many values for money. Dictionary<string,List<int>> Values = new Dictionary<string,List<int>>();
   Values.Add("Money",MoneyList);
   Values.Add("Income",IncomeList);     ///where moneyList is list of all money and incomeList is list of all income

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Class:

```
public class YourClassName
{
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public int Income { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
foreach (YourClassName item in items)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Money = {item.Money}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Income = {item.Income}");
}
```

And store it in a list like this:

```
List<YourClassName> items = new List<YourClassName>();
items.Add(new YourClassName()
{
    Income = 5,
    Money = 100
});
```